# How to add GLTF Model in THREEJS level?

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge

I want to create an extension that can load gltf once the method is call. I'm using the latest threejs module according to this [blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-add-newest-threejs-features-forge-viewer). But got an error.
[image]

Here's my code.

```
   const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
  let example = new THREE.Object3D();
  gltfLoader.load(
    "https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/models/cartoon_lowpoly_small_city_free_pack/scene.gltf",
    (gltf) => {
      example = gltf.scene;
      console.log(example);
      if (!this.viewer.overlays.hasScene("gltf")) {
        this.viewer.overlays.addScene("gltf");
      }
      this.viewer.overlays.addMesh(example, "gltf");
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the glTF, you may check out this blog post and consider using the `Autodesk.glTF` ext instead: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/gltf-20-support-forge-viewer

```js
viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.glTF').then(() => {
    viewer.loadModel('address/of/your/model.gltf');
});
```

See here for the code sample: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app/tree/experiment/gltf2

Here's a couple of things to keep in mind when working with glTF files in Forge Viewer:

- The viewer extension does not aim to be fully compliant with the glTF 2.0 specification

  - For example, the material/shader system in Forge Viewer is different from the PBR (physically-based rendering) materials used in glTF, so the viewer will not be able to represent all glTF materials to their full extent
  - Some features of the file format such as animations are not supported
- If the glTF file defines multiple objects in a tree structure, the individual objects will be selectable in the viewer and the tree structure will appear in the Model Browser dialog; note however that many glTF files store the entire scene as a single object
- The glTF specification does not use any concept of metadata attached to individual elements; the Properties dialog in the viewer will therefore not provide any additional information about selected elements

Comment: thanks for your reply. When I import the gltf model using `Autodesk.glTF` I always get an error: "Sorry, we seems to have technical dificullties and could't complete your request .....". Second, I want to load it based on API trigger. it's likely to be modeling in the viewer multiple times, this is why I'm working on it in threeJS. Then if I use Autodesk.gltf how do I move the model dynamically after loaded?

Comment: Are you directly loading the glTF files from `three.js` org? If yes, it could be a [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) problem since the common web browsers will block such kinds of requests unless the website accepts wildcard CORS requests. I would advise you to download the glTF files and the above demo code sample to your local machine and run the app locally.

Comment: Working with  https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app/tree/experiment/gltf2, you will need to put the downloaded glTF models into the `public/models` folder, then change [this line](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app/blob/experiment/gltf2/public/main.js#L9) pointing to your model.

Comment: Thanks. It works after I export my gltf model in blender with separate format (gltf, bin and texture). And about my second question. How to select specific gltf after multiple model loaded ? I [read](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/dynamic-model-placement) there is a `placementTransform` that I can use. But it seems that it can only be used in the initial setup.

Comment: After loading the model, we can call `Model.setPlacementTransform` to change the `PlacementTransform` as the blog post does.